# Heroku Rails 5 App Doesn't Load JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a single page Rails 5 app to Heroku, and everything seems to deploy just fine EXCEPT the JavaScript file. I have one static.js file within the `app/assets/javascripts` folder (besides the application.js). It all works in localhost, but not when deployed on Heroku.

I know that it has something to do with precompiling the assets pipeline for Heroku, but I don't really understand how to specifically do that. Any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `config/environments/production.rb` those line like this

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

do a git add/commit cycle, then re-deploy to Heroku.

Comment: Yep! I had those lines, as well as:
**config.assets.compress = true**
I think I just don't have the JS code in the right place maybe?

Comment: In your `application.js` `//= require static` under the `jquery`

Comment: Hm, I don't see any errors in the production log... and I do have `//= require static` in `application.js` I have it under the `//=require tree .` also, doesn't //=require tree . take care of including all files within the app/assets/js folder?

Comment: I also tried putting all my JS code into `application.js` and deploying, but I still can't seem to get the JS code to work

Comment: Sometimes it missing, like I have used something like this on some rails application

Comment: Yea, that was my thought too about the `//=require static`, it's so weird that my JS code is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
config.assets.compile = true

config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

to config/environments/production.rb

Then, run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

```
git push heroku master
```